# javascript: how do i get the value of a specific attribute in a nested div

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

To simplify what I want to achieve, I want to get **popular-laptop-deals** from data-code="popular-laptop-deals" using a javascript bookmarklet alert.

```
<div class="display-table-column scroll-item display-block-xs top-padding-mini-xs tile-highlight category-tile" data-code="popular-laptop-deals" data-testid="tile-highlight">
```

These belong to a nested div where there are other `<div>` with data-code="". I'm trying to get the function to run through all and get all the other values from data-code="".

I have tried using the following script but it returns "undefined":

```js
javascript:alert(document.getElementsByName("data-code")[0]);
```

Appreciate if someone could show or guide me on how i can achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByName("data-code")` is an empty NodeList because there are no elements with `name`s, hence, no element with attribute `data-code`.

You can change `getElementsByName` to `getElementsByTagName`, etc. and then get its attribute value.

Also, `data-*` attributes can be accessed via the `dataset` property of an element, e.g. `yourDiv.dataset.code`.

```js
alert(document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0].dataset.code);
```

```html
<div class="display-table-column scroll-item display-block-xs top-padding-mini-xs tile-highlight category-tile" data-code="popular-laptop-deals" data-testid="tile-highlight">
```

Answer (score 1):

With this, you can check all div tags on the page and add them to the array if contain data-code.

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
var result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i++) {
    if (typeof divs[i].dataset.code !== "undefined") {
        result.push(divs[i].dataset.code);
    }
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery, you can achieve like as below.

Jquery:

```js
alert($("div").attr("data-code"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="display-table-column scroll-item display-block-xs top-padding-mini-xs tile-highlight category-tile" data-code="popular-laptop-deals" data-testid="tile-highlight">
```

Answer (score 0):

with `querySelector` select tag and with `getAttribute` select attribute

```js
var attr_code = document.querySelector('div').getAttribute('data-code');
alert(attr_code);
```

```html
<div class="display-table-column scroll-item display-block-xs top-padding-mini-xs tile-highlight category-tile" data-code="popular-laptop-deals" data-testid="tile-highlight">
```